# VolleyError with null when invoking local rest api developed using PHP

Tags: android, android-volley

I have developed a php RestAPI and when i invoke them Postman, it is working fine. I am getting required responses:
http://192.168.23.33/wopo/v1/registerUser.php

When i am calling the above API call with volley, it is getting into "public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)" where error is also null.

I have configure the above same URL while sending the StringRequest? Is that fine?

```
stringRequest=new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, Constants.URL_Register, new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.d("mysuccess","I saw success");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),json.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LandingScreenActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Log.d("myerror","I got some error");
                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        Log.d("myerror1",error.getMessage());
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
            {

                int userRole=0;
                if(buyerCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                    if (selleCheckbox.isChecked())
                        userRole = 3;
                    else
                        userRole = 2;
                }else
                if(selleCheckbox.isChecked())
                    userRole=2;

                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                params.put("userid","1");
                params.put("username",strUsername);
                params.put("emailaddress",strEmail);
                params.put("housenumber",strFlatNumber);
                params.put("apartmentname",apartname);
                params.put("apartmentaddress",useraddress);
                params.put("usertype",String.valueOf(userRole));

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Do you have Antivirus programs installed in your system (Avast or AVG etc)? Please check your system Firewall once. Turn it off and try to send request again.

Comment: @Shashanth i have bit defender? will it also block?

Comment: I'm not sure. Avast and AVG free antivirus programs some times block the request. Turn it off for some time and turn off Firewall also. Do you have the same network (LAN) for your system and mobile? If possible, please post Postman screenshots.

Comment: OMG, i was breaking my head from last couple of hours checking emulator, real device et.... after i turn off my bitdefender, it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy coding...